# how to make google maps infowindow pop up after clicking list item

Tags: google-maps-api-3, knockout.js

I have a list of items on one side of screen and google maps api displaying markers on the other.  I'd like the infowindow of anyone particular marker to pop up when the respective list item is clicked.  I already managed to get the infowindow of the markers to pop up when you click on the actual marker, however now I want to get it working with the list I created as well.  For example, When I click on Madison Square Garden in the list I'd like the Madison Square Garden marker to display the infowindow in the google maps api.

here is html using knockout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Neighborhood Map Project</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="searchmenu">
        <input id="searchbox"placeholder="Search..." type="search" daatabind="value: query, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" autocomplete="off">
        <div id="menu">
            <ul data-bind="foreach: locations">
                <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDsK_DgDME2t1k3F0AFiP52F28hDu9nie4&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

and js as follows:

```
var locations = [{
    name: "Red Bull Arena",
    address: "600 Cape May St, Harrison, NJ 07029",
    lat: 40.737046,
    long: -74.150361
}, {
    name: "MetLife Stadium",
    address: "1 MetLife Stadium Dr, East Rutherford, NJ 07073",
    lat: 40.813091,
    long: -74.074209
}, {
    name: "World Trade Center",
    address: "285 Fulton St, New York, NY 10007",
    lat: 40.713175,
    long: -74.013104
}, {
    name: "Zeppelin Hall Biergarten",
    address: "88 Liberty View Dr, Jersey City, NJ 07302",
    lat: 40.715120,
    long: -74.046754
}, {
    name: "Prudential Center",
    address: "25 Lafayette St, Newark, NJ 07102",
    lat: 40.733617,
    long: -74.171150
}, {
    name: "Madison Square Garden",
    address: "4 Pennsylvania Plaza, New York, NY 10001",
    lat: 40.750691,
    long: -73.993476
}];


var Location = function(data) {
    this.name = ko.observable(data.title);
    this.address = ko.observable(data.address);
    this.lat = ko.observable(data.lat);
    this.long = ko.observable(data.long);
};

var viewModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    this.locationList = ko.observableArray([]);
    locations.forEach(function(locationItem) {
        self.locationList.push(new Location(locationItem));
    });

    this.currentLocation = ko.observable(this.locationList()[0]);
    this.setLocation = function(clickedLocation) {
        self.currentLocation(clickedLocation);
        google.maps.event.trigger(clickedLocation.marker, 'click');
    };

    this.places = ko.observableArray(locations);
    this.query = ko.observable("");

};



function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 12,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.753011, -74.128069)
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker;



    function createMarker(latlng, html) {
        html = '<h3>' + locations[i].name + '</h3>' + locations[i].address;
        latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].lat, locations[i].long);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(html);
            infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
    return marker;
    }


    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            createMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][2], locations[i][3]));
    }




ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
}
```

https://github.com/matosb2/P5/tree/develop

Comment: You're setting `name` to `title`, but `locations` have `name`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've already set up a click handler (as `setLocation`) in your viewmodel, so all you really need is a click binding for it.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: locations">
    <li data-bind="text: name, click: setLocation"></li>
</ul>
```

Nicely, your click handler expects the clicked location as an argument, and [that is what the click binding will give it](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html#note-1-passing-a-current-item-as-a-parameter-to-your-handler-function).

One thing is missing, though: `setLocation` expects the location object to have a `marker` member, but you don't create that member anywhere. One possible way to do this is in your loop where you call `createMarker`, just add the marker as a member to the current element of `locations`. Oh, that loop thinks `locations` is an array of arrays, rather than an array of objects. It should look like:

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    locations[i].marker = createMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].lat, locations[i].long));
}
```

Get rid of your `Location` constructor, it's providing you nothing. Just initialize `locationList` like so:

```
this.locationList = ko.observableArray(locations);
```

Comment: Your answer helped somewhat.  I got it working by mainly adding the click and $parent bindings to the list view.  I then fixed up the for loop like you said.  From that point on it was working like I wanted it to.  When I tried removing the Location constructor it messed up the list and that didn't display properly so I kept it normal and untouched.  Also I already have the locationList initializing in my code, however when I passed locations as a parameter instead, it repeated itself and now I had 2 sets of same locations repeating on my list so I kept that the same as well.